# Help me understand how to use a Fourier Series to calculate an Σ sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fourier-series, transformation, periodic-functions

So, we're given a function $f(x) =
\begin{cases}
2,  &-\pi < x\le 0 \\
6, &0 < x\le\pi
\end{cases}$, while $f(x+2π) = f(x)$ for any $x\in\Bbb R$.

Now, I've calculated the Fourier series of $f(x)$, which is $$F = 2+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{8\sin(\frac{πn}{2})}{πn}\cos(nx)+\frac{4(1-\cos(\frac{πn}{2}))}{πn}\sin(nx)\right)$$

We're then supposed to use this Fourier series $F$, to calculate this sum $\sum_{k=0}^∞  \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}$.

I've read some other replies here regarding the same subject, but I just cannot understand how to do this.
Can someone help me understand what I'm supposed to do?

Comment: The DC term is usually the average which is $4$ here. So, without checking the details, something is off. The denominators should be of the form $2n+1$.

Comment: I got the Fourier series as$$f(x)=4+\frac4\pi\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1-\cos(n\pi)}n\sin(nx)$$Since $1-\cos(n\pi)=0$ for even $n$, we can also write$$f(x)=4+\frac8\pi\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin((2n-1)x)}{2n-1}$$

Comment: @copper.hat $1-\cos(n\pi)=0$ for even $n$

Comment: @ShubhamJohri: Seems like an answer to me with the fact that the series converges pointwise except at transition points.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, will need to recheck my calculations. But what about using the Fourier series to find the ∑ sum?

Comment: Plugging in $x=\pm\pi/2$ should do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the Fourier series as$$f(x)=4+\frac4\pi\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1-\cos(n\pi)}n\sin(nx)$$Since $1-\cos(n\pi)=0$ for even $n$, we can also write$$f(x)=4+\frac8\pi\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\sin\big((2n+1)x\big)}{2n+1}$$$x=\pi/2$ is  a point of continuity, so the series converges to $f(\pi/2)=6$ at the point.$$\implies6=4+\frac8\pi\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\sin\big((2n+1)\pi/2\big)}{2n+1}\\\implies\frac\pi4=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n}}{2n+1}$$